# multiple <select> dropdown as sql parameters | PHP

Tags: php, html, xampp, sqlsrv

I have a running code that does sql query based on 1 `<select>` dropdown value. May I ask how will I be able to do multiple query parameters using 2 or more `<select>` dropdown?

Example. I sorted my data based on `accounttitle` now I want to sort `accountttitle` by `YEAR(datedue)`, how will I do this?

This is what I got so far.

For `isset()`

```
  if(isset($_GET['accounttitle'])){
    $accounttitle = $_GET['accounttitle'];

    $year = date('Y');
  if(isset($_GET['year'])){
    $year = $_GET['year'];
  }
  else "PLEASE SELECT OPTION";
  } 
  ?>
```

For `<select>`

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
<select class="form-control" id="select_account_title" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
  <option value="">PLEASE SELECT OPTION</option>
  <?php while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
    <option value="<?= urlencode($row['accounttitle'])?>"><?= $row['accounttitle'] ?></option>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<label>Select Year: </label>
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="select_year">
                      <?php
                        for($i=2013; $i<=2033; $i++){
                          $selected = ($i==$year)?'selected':'';
                          echo "
                            <option value='".$i."' ".$selected.">".$i."</option>
                          ";
                        }
                      ?>
                    </select>
</div>
```

For `SQL`

```
                    $sql = "SELECT referenceno, employeeidno, accounttitle, 'ON PROGRESS' as debit, postedby, approvedby, notedby, credit FROM earningsamendment where accounttitle= '$accounttitle' and YEAR(datedue)='$year'";
                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

This is my concern.

```
$(function(){
  $('#select_account_title').change(function(){
    window.location.href = 'earnings_amendment.php?accounttitle='+$(this).val();
  });
});
</script>
```

How will I enable `<script>` to read 2 parameters? like

```
$(function(){
  $('#select_account_title').change(function(){
    window.location.href = 'earnings_amendment.php?accounttitle='+$(accounttitle).val()'&year='+$(year).val();
  });
});
</script>
```

or something similar?

Comment: @Dharman noted on this. i will fix everything once all is working. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an on change with multiple selectors.

```
$(document).on('change', '#select_account_title, #select_year', function() {
    var account_title = $("#select_account_title").val();
    var year = $("#select_year").val();

    window.location.href = 'earnings_amendment.php?accounttitle='+account_title+'&year='+year;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! this is just what I need! you're a life saver, if you don't mind. can you provide me a better link to study ````<script>```` I'm having a hard time understanding the guides in the internet.